# How to apply validation on Datepicker through javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have a date-picker in JavaScript as:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

Now I want the user to select date which are less than today i.e. to select any dates which are previous or before  from today.how to apply such validation on date?

Answer (score 0):

Date picker has maxDate property which will enable us to set the maximum date. As per your requirement the date must be previous from today. Then it will be like this

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: -1 });
     });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
  $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({  maxDate: -1 });
   });
</script>

<input type='text' id='datepicker'>
```

Comment: I applied it but then also I'm able to select date ahead of today.

Comment: I just want to select any date which are before from today.Validation to be applied only when user select today or ahead of today dates.

Comment: @MES can you please check the code snippet. Is that you require.

Comment: yup,I require user to select any date before today .I applied this on my code.But I'm able to select 20 feb 2015.